# Unable to update boolean value in sailsjs waterline

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm working on a project that is built on top of SailsJS but now i'm writing the Update process for a document and when i'm doing this, getting the following error.

```
   {
      "code": "E_VALIDATION",
      "invalidAttributes": {
      "deleted": [
      {
        "rule": "boolean",
        "message": "\"boolean\" validation rule failed for input: 'true'\nSpecifically, it threw an error.  Details:\n undefined"
      }
    ]}
  }
```

In the Model I've

```
    deleted: {
        type: 'string',
        boolean: true
    }
```

In Controller
    // Action for deleting a specified User
    destroy: function( req, res, next ) {

```
    // Logs actions details
    sails.log.info("Attempting to delete user ( " , req.param('id') , " ) from IP (IP adddress: " , req.ip , ")" );

    User.update({
        id: req.param('id')
    }, {
        deleted: true
    }).exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) {

            // Handles the response containing some error
            ErrorHandler.response(err, req, res, next);
        }

        res.json(user);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boolean` is not a [validation rule](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/validations) in Sails.js. You should use `type: 'boolean'` instead. See [list of model attributes](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/attributes).

In your `User` model:

```
deleted: {
    type: 'boolean'
}
```